# How to show that a random variable has to be a constant if it is independent to a particular random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Imagine we have X random variable uniform(0,1) on the probability space ([0,1], Borel, Leb).
and Z another random variable on the same probability space, such that X and Z are independent.
How do we show that Z has to be a constant almost surely?
I tried for hours but I have no idea where to begin. If anyone could help that would be very appreciated thank you!

Comment: If you were able to show that $X$ was a function of $Z$, your conclusion would follow.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:** Given $\omega\in[0,1]$ let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots$ be the binary digits of $\omega$. Define $X(\omega) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\omega_{2n}\over 2^n}$ and $Z(\omega) = \omega_1$. Then $X$ is uniformly distributed, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent, but $Z$ is not constant.

(I suspect you intended, without saying so, for $X$ to be the random variable $X(\omega) =\omega$, $\omega\in[0,1]$.)

Comment: Hello, i dont really understand why it is 2 and not . if ()= , then we should have ()=∑={}/(2^) no? also in my exercise they say we should prove that Z has to be a constant so I am a bit confused

Comment: In my example, the r.v. $X$ is **not** the identity function.

Comment: oh yes I got my mistake, I assumed it was equivalent but it was not. X should be the identity indeed